Find the radius of a circle given 2 of its coordinates and their angles.
I am in a real-life situation where I need to calculate the radius of a circle in a coordinate system.
The circle is NOT centered at the origin.
I know two points on this circle, $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$ and they are $285^\circ$ and $330^\circ$ counter-clockwise from the CENTER of the circle (not the origin).
I crucially do not know the coordinates of the center of the circle.
Trying to set up an analytic equation gets me nowhere because I have $2$ equations and $3$ unknowns.
$$(1-h)^2+(-k)^2=r^2$$
$$(2-h)^2+(1-k)^2=r^2$$
I feel as if I need to use a vector equation and have it "shifted" by a variable.
$$r\sin(\theta)=y-k$$
My thought process is that $r\sin(\theta)$ for a vector at the origin would equal the $y$ value of any of my coordinates if I shifted them vertically by $k$.
I know $\sin(330)$ is $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin(285)$ is $-\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}{4}$
And from here I try to solve the system of equations by plug and chug.
$$r\sin(330)=1-k$$
$$r\sin(285)=-k$$
However when I solve using this method I consistently get a radius $-1+\sqrt2+\sqrt3$, but when I try to make my circle again only $(1,0)$ is on the circle and $(2,1)$ is inside the circle just to the left of whatever the point $285^\circ$ into the circle is.
I keep either making the same mistake or such a circle is not possible and I need to opt for an ellipse, for which then I need to solve for two radii, same question.

The question is weird that the chord between $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$ has angle $\arctan \frac11 = 45^\circ$. The perpendicular bisector of this chord has angle $315^\circ$, which does not bisect the angle between the given $285^\circ$ and $330^\circ$.

Please include a picture/diagram of this if possible.

Instead of giving up the circle and going to an ellipse, we could also keep the circle and give up the requirement that the zero-direction for angles must be parallel to a coordinate axis. We can still maintain that the points $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$ come in that order when going counterclockwise, and that their arc has length $330^\circ-285^\circ=45^\circ$. This gives the following circle equation: $$\left( x-\left(1-\tfrac12 \sqrt 2\right) \right)^2 + \left( y-\left(1+\tfrac12 \sqrt 2\right) \right)^2 = 2+\sqrt 2$$ I believe this is also what the answer by Crowley (below) is about.

You know the slopes of the two lines through the two points, so you can find where they intersect. The intersection point is $(\frac12, 1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$. However, your two points are not at the same distance from that intersection point. So your points aren't on a circle with the given angles.
The radial distances are $\sqrt{\sqrt{3} + 2} \approx 1.931852$ and $\sqrt{3} \approx 1.732051$.
Here's a diagram, produced using SageMath.


The second part of your question asks for an ellipse centred on that intersection point which passes through the two given points. The simplest such ellipse is aligned with the X and Y coordinate axes. The equation of an axis-aligned ellipse centred on $(x_0, y_0)$ is
$$\left(\frac{x-x_0}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y-y_0}{b}\right)^2 = 1$$
The radial distance $r$ of a point on the ellipse with polar angle $\phi$ is given by
$$\frac1{r^2} = \left(\frac{\cos(\phi)}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sin(\phi)}{b}\right)^2$$
Thus we can find $a, b$ from the angles and radii by solving the matrix equation
$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\cos^2(\phi_1) & \sin^2(\phi_1) \\
\cos^2(\phi_2) & \sin^2(\phi_2) \\
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1/a^2 \\ 1/b^2 \\
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1/r_1^2 \\ 1/r_2^2 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$
This gives $a \approx 1.673033$
and $b \approx 1.955392$.
Here is the resulting ellipse.

Here's the Sage script that I used to do the calculations and create the plots.

There are also some solutions involving a rotated ellipse. For example, here's one rotated by 30°.

Please see the Sage script for details of the calculation procedure. If you choose an invalid rotation angle $\alpha$, $a$ and/or $b$ will have ridiculously large or complex values, and the Sage plotter will get confused. ;)

You should make the given points bigger. They are pretty difficult to see.

@qwr I've updated my answer.

I find this answer much clearer than the accepted one, showing clearly upfront why there’s no circle fitting the OP’s criteria.
